# Creating method for string without creating prototype

Tags: javascript, methods

I want to create a method that you can call like 'string'.doSth() without creating a new string prototype. How can I do it?

Comment: why not set your function like this then: function doSth('string').

Comment: I know the way to do it with prototype and function declaration/expression, just curious if there is a way to do it without using these ways.

Comment: @user2734550: No. `'string'` is a `String`, and if you want to put methods on that you have to amend one of its prototypes - either `String.prototype` or `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Can you describe what your real objective is here?  The way you add methods to an object type in Javascript is to add methods to the existing prototype for that type of object (`String.prototype` in this case).  That's how you do it.  So, why are you asking how to not do it the way that the language is designed to do?  Gives us a clue about why you don't want to do it the supported way so we might have a clue how to help you.

Comment: Just curious if there are possibilities to do so. I am still trying to understand this language as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I noticed you DON'T want String.prototype

Avoid using it by doing something like:

```
window.doSth = function (s) {
    return s + '!';
};
```

---

Or, you can make your own constructor:

```
var SpecialString = function (s) {
    this.value = s;
    this.doSth = function () {
        return this.value + '!';
    };
};
```

Now:

```
var myString = new SpecialString('Foo');
myString.value; // Its value, Foo
myString.doSth(); // Returns Foo!
```

#### I'll leave the rest just in case you change your mind

## `this` and `String.prototype`

You can use `String.prototype`. This will let you "add functions" to string. To get the string, use `this`:

```
String.prototype.doSth = function () {
    alert(this);
};

var testString = 'Foo Bar';
testString.doSth(); // Alerts "Foo Bar"
```

---

## Using `return`

Use `return` to produce a new value. Let's say you wanted this function to add an exclamation mark *`!`* to the end of the string:

```
String.prototype.addExclamation = function () {
    return this + '!';
};
```

Now:

```
var testString = "Foo";
var newString = testString.addExclamation();
alert(newString); // Alerts Foo!
```

---

Comment: Doesn't work. I think you meant to write function SpecialString(s){}; Plus 'new'

Answer (score 1):

Only other way is to just not create a global function and add it to `String`

```
String.doSth = function(str) {
  //do something
}
String.doSth('hi');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can allways augment the prototype of String. Here's how

```
   String.prototype.doSomething = function () {
     console.log('doing something');
   }

   var a = 'str';
   a.doSomething();
```

Comment: *without creating a new string prototype.*

Comment: The String prototype is there. You are not creating it. You are adding a new method to an existing prototype object

Comment: Take a look at comment on OP. I goofed up and missed that :P

Answer (score 0):

By writing `'string'` you are basically creating a new string object.
If you add a `doSth` method to the string prototype, it will be callable:

```
String.prototype.doSth = function doSth() {
  console.log('Inside');
}
"string".doSth(); // will log 'Inside'
```

Comment: Did someone down-vote my answer due to a bad description of the problem in the question? Or is there something else wrong with the question?